# Format Not Accepting Tuple Inputs

Tags: format

I understand the way to use format is string.format(value1,value2...) Why is my code below giving an error? When I manually write print (b.format('2♥', '2♣')) it prints correctly, but when I substitute the input for suit_list, I get an index error that index 1 is out of range.

```
suit_list = ('2♥', '2♣')

b= ('| {} | ')*2

print (b.format(suit_list))


________________________________
print (b.format(suit_list))

Expect: | 2♥ | | 2♣ |
```

Comment: Is this [tag:python]? You shouldn't _expect_ passing a single tuple to do the same thing as two separate strings, but you could _unpack_ it `.format(*suit_list)`.